# using the cordova screenorientation plugin with webview

Tags: ios, cordova, webview, screen, orientation

I am using the [Cordova plugin by yoik](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation), which helps locking/unlocking orientation on iOS. The issue is for me it doesn't work at all -

```
screen.lockOrientation('portrait')
```

Its probably related to Webview, as it works on iframe.

How does the cordova plugin work ? Why doesn't my simple line execute as expected? Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using ionic?

Comment: If you're trying to do this on first page load, are you waiting for `deviceready` to fire before calling `screen.lockOrientation`?

Comment: Yes, I am. It works fine on iframe, does nothing with wkwebview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a plugin which works with wkwebview too -

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-screenorientation-for-wkwebview

It is forked from [Cordova plugin by yoik](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation).

Hope this helps, if someone is facing a similar issue.